# Discord.py events not working after adding new events

Tags: python, discord, ctypes

I am using discord.py, and every time I add a new event to my script, the older ones do not work. Not sure what the problem is, as I have included the  await client.process_commands(message) at the end. Most of the code near the top is for the keypresses and have nothing to do with the discord api. Help is appreciated!

Code: (code I am having issues with is near the bottom.)

```
from os import waitpid
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import client

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput
 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

#EVENTS I AM HAVING ISSUES WITH#######################################

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('w'):
        KeyPress()
    await client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('a'):
        SKey()
    await client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('d'):
        DKey()
    await client.process_commands(message)

#########################################################

def KeyPress():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    PressKey(0x11) 
    time.sleep(.05)
    ReleaseKey(0x11) 

def SKey():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    PressKey(0x1e) 
    time.sleep(.05)
    ReleaseKey(0x1e) 

def DKey():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    PressKey(0x20) 
    time.sleep(.05)
    ReleaseKey(0x20) 

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one "on_message" event, otherwise, the latest one override the others.

Instead, combine them using multiple if statements.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('w'):
        KeyPress()

    if message.content.startswith('a'):
        SKey()

    if message.content.startswith('d'):
        DKey()
    await client.process_commands(message)
```